# Isn't Integer a reference? Why doesnt an inc not update a hashmap value?

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

I was expecting that the following snippets are equivalent:

```
Integer count = occurences.get(c);  
if(count == null) {  
   count = 0;  
   occurences.put(c, count);   
}  
++count;
```

and

```
Integer count = occurences.get(c);  
if(count == null) {  
    count = 0;  
    occurences.put(c, count);  
}  
occurences.put(c, count + 1);
```

But when I run the program the first snippet always has the `count` as 0.
Why is that? Since `Integer` is a reference in the `HashMap` why isn't the increment reflected and I need to do a `put`?

Comment: Because it's not a reference to the element.

Comment: @AndyTurner:I didn't understand

Answer (score 3):

`count` is a local variable. It points to an instance of an immutable class, `Integer`.

When you increment it with:

```
++count;
```

that's just syntactic sugar for:

```
count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1);
```

You're reassigning `count`. That's all.

Comment: Why is it a local variable though? We save it in the hasmap. For what type of object would my code work then?

Comment: @Jim you don't store *variables* in the hash map: you store the value pointed to by the variable in the hash map (or not: you can put values that aren't assigned to variables into a map). Subsequent updates to the variable aren't reflected in the map.

Comment: But all the variables are references. So am I putting the actual content? So how do we get all these memory leaks by keep references inside a hashmap that we so often read about?

Comment: In the first line of my answer I state: "It points [The reference refers] to an instance of an immutable class, `Integer`". It is not referring to anything to do with the `Map`. It's just reference to a number. You can't change that number; all you can do is make that reference refer to a different number.

Comment: This has little to do with the immutability of `Integer`, and more that `++count` is defined (more or less) as `count = (Integer)((int)count + 1)`.